# Manually wiring CompletableFutures instead of using API

Tags: java, completable-future, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I've been digging into [AWS SDK Java v2](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) async code, and I see [a lot](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/f1fd88e11d7fdf73f6ad1c87bf198588d2824c73/core/sdk-core/src/main/java/software/amazon/awssdk/core/internal/http/pipeline/stages/MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java#L82-L118) of this pattern:

```java
CompletableFuture<Response<OutputT>> toReturn = new CompletableFuture<>();
(...)
CompletableFutureUtils.forwardExceptionTo(requestFuture, toReturn);

CompletableFutureUtils.forwardExceptionTo(toReturn, requestFuture);

requestFuture.thenAccept(request -> {

            try {
                CompletableFuture<Response<OutputT>> executeFuture = executeHttpRequest(request, context);

                executeFuture.whenComplete((r, t) -> {
                    if (t != null) {
                        toReturn.completeExceptionally(t);
                    } else {
                        toReturn.complete(r);
                    }
                });

                CompletableFutureUtils.forwardExceptionTo(toReturn, executeFuture);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                toReturn.completeExceptionally(t);
            }
        });

return toReturn;
```

What's the advantage of such manually wiring of the futures, instead of a more linear approach? Such as

```java
return requestFuture.thenAccept(request -> executeHttpRequest(request, context));
```

Thanks.

Comment: It might be a way to properly handle cancellations. The thing about cancelling a `CompletableFuture` is that it only cancels _that stage_ by completing it exceptionally with a `CancellationException` (and obviously dependent stages can react to that). However, it does not affect previous/parent stages. Nor does cancelling a `CompletableFuture` interrupt any thread. This means you have to write rather convoluted code to watch for a cancellation and _actually stop_ doing what you're doing in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Slaw. Why would we want to cancel previous stages - I reason they'd already be completed and thus not eligible for cancelation. Or perhaps that's for some parallel execution kind of pipeline?

Comment: I don't know the whole code, and obviously I'm just guessing, but consider if you have stages `A -> B`, and you have access to `B` via a method return. The bulk of the work, however, is being done by `A`. You want to cancel that work, so you call `cancel()` on `B`. That only completes `B` exceptionally. The `A` stage is still happily running in the background. So, you've "cancelled" the work, but the work is still executing. Ideally, cancelling `B` will also stop `A` from continuing, but `CompletableFuture` does not really provide this functionality. Thus, the convoluted code.

Comment: Makes total sense, thanks. If I understand correctly, if I have a `CompletableFuture` pipeline, and I have access to the first future, I can cancel it and it will send the `CancellationException` forward. OTOH, if I only have access to the last future, cancelling it is almost a no-ops if execution is still in a prior step - hence the need for this kind of code. Is that right?

Comment: Essentially, yeah. Though it's a little more complicated for the stage doing the actual work if you want said work to _stop_. And I'd like to stress again that I'm only guessing, and the real purpose might be tangential to what I'm saying, or even something else entirely. Without reading the entire execution path in the source code, I can't be sure. Ideally, a definitive answer would be given by a developer of this code.

Comment: Sure, I've tagged the AWS team here and on twitter, let's see if someone reaches out. But what you brought makes total sense and exception forwarding - and now that I see it, actually propagating exceptions backwards - seems to be a major concern throughout this pipeline. If you'd be willing to write this as an answer, I think I'll keep the post open for a while, but I'd at least upvote it, and sure should be helpful for anyone landing up here afterwards.

Comment: One last question if you wouldn't mind - you mention cancelling the running future would be tricky - I understand that even if I have access to it directly or propagate the `CancellationException`. I'll sure do some more research on the topic, but is there any direction you can point me to regarding what would be a proper way for dealing with that?

Comment: Sure, it makes sense. Not sure if you've seen the original file in the link, it has comments that corroborate your thinking. Going down the rabbit hole, this gets to their Netty NIO Client, and there's a `Promise` abstraction and that might properly react to cancellation. And it all makes sense considering the SDK returns a future to the user, so they want to react to user cancellation.

Comment: The happy news for me is that in my solution users have no access to underlying `CompletableFutures`. The API users have to stop execution shuts down the `Executor` passed to `supplyAsync`, so any running `Tasks` are properly interrupted - thus I might not need such wiring. I might still have some work to do to not have `InterruptedException` trigger usual `exceptionally` calls, since it might trigger yet another execution when probably users expect executions to end.

Comment: The main reason most likely is that `executeHttpRequest` can throw *checked exceptions*, i.e. `IOException`, which a `Function` is not allowed to throw. So you need to deal with `CompletableFuture` manually, when you want to call `completeExceptionally` rather than wrapping the exception in another unchecked exception. It still could have been done simpler, though. There’s no point in this bidirectional `forwardExceptionTo(requestFuture, toReturn)`  plus `forwardExceptionTo(toReturn, requestFuture)`, as the second future can only fail after the first has been completed (`thenAccept` logic).

Comment: If you need to throw an exception from a Function/Callable/Runnable inside a Future you wrap it in an unchecked CompletionException. This is what CompletableFuture does to all exceptions anyway.